# ffmpeg -vf: command not found

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I am still a semi-novice at ffmpeg. I can  do the basics with 1-pass crf encoding but as I am venturing into 2-pass encoding, I am running into an error I cannot solve. Any help is appreciated.

In short, when I run the following script in Ubuntu,

```
IFS=$'\n'

for i in `ls  *.{ts,mkv,mpeg,mpg,mov,avi,mp4,m2t,mts}`
    do
        #Output naming scheme
        extension=`echo "$i" | egrep -o '\.(ts|mkv|mpeg|mpg|mov|avi|mp4|mts)$'`     
        extensionFreeFileName=$(echo "$i" | awk -F `echo ${extension}` '{print $1}')        
        newFileName="$extensionFreeFileName"

        #Extract proper frame rate from source video
        testFrameFormat='/'
        testFramsString=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  "`

        if [[ "$testFramsString" =~ "$testFrameFormat" ]]; then
            frameRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  " | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}' | head -1`
        else
            frameRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  " | awk -F "\: " '{print $2}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | head -1`
        fi

        #Video bit rate lookup and calculations
        videoBitRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Bit rate  " | head -1 | tail -1 | awk -F' : ' '{print $2}' | awk -F' kb/s' '{print $1}' | sed 's| ||g'`
        videoBitRate=$((videoBitRate * 1024))

        avc35BitRate=$((videoBitRate * 35 / 100))
        avc25BitRate=$((videoBitRate * 25 / 100))
        hevc30BitRate=$((videoBitRate * 30 / 100))
        hevc27BitRate=$((videoBitRate * 27 / 100))
        hevc24BitRate=$((videoBitRate * 24 / 100))
        hevc21BitRate=$((videoBitRate * 21 / 100))
        hevc17BitRate=$((videoBitRate * 17 / 100))

        #check to ensure calculations are being performed as expected
        echo -e "\n\n\n\n"
        echo -e "$i"
        echo -e "$frameRate"
        echo -e "$videoBitRate"
        echo -e "$avc35BitRate"
        echo -e "$avc25BitRate"
        echo -e "$hevc30BitRate"
        echo -e "$hevc27BitRate"
        echo -e "$hevc24BitRate"
        echo -e "$hevc21BitRate"
        echo -e "$hevc17BitRate"
        echo -e "\n\n\n"

        #Encoding command (two-pass, multiple outputs)
        ~/bin/ffmpeg -analyzeduration 500000000 -probesize 500000000 -i "$i" -preset veryslow \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc30BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc30" -an -f matroska /dev/null \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc27BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc27" -an -f matroska /dev/null \        
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc24BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc24" -an -f matroska /dev/null \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc21BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc21" -an -f matroska /dev/null \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc17BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc17" -an -f matroska /dev/null \
            -vf yadif -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$avc35BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName avc35" -an -f matroska /dev/null \
            -vf yadif -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$avc25BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName avc25" -an -f matroska /dev/null &&
        ~/bin/ffmpeg -analyzeduration 500000000 -probesize 500000000 -i "$i" -preset veryslow \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc30BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc30" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 30pct).mkv" \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc27BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc27" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 27pct).mkv" \     
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc24BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc24" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 24pct).mkv" \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc21BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc21" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 21pct).mkv" \
            -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc17BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc17" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 17pct).mkv" \
            -vf yadif -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$avc35BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName avc35" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (AVC 35pct).mkv" \
            -vf yadif -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$avc25BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName avc25" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (AVC 25pct).mkv"
done;
```

---

**I get the following errors:**

```
TwoPassConvert_A-Z.sh: line 50: -vf: command not found
TwoPassConvert_A-Z.sh: line 58: -vf: command not found
```

which reference the following lines in the script, respectively:

```
-vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc24BitRate" -x265-params pass=1 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc24" -an -f matroska /dev/null \
-vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:V "$hevc24BitRate" -x265-params pass=2 -passlogfile "$extensionFreeFileName hevc24" -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 24pct).mkv" \
```

Any help you can provide in correcting this error would be appreciated.

---

Additionally, when the script runs, I get the following prompt:

```
File '/dev/null' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]
```

Is there a way I can always answer 'yes' when running the script?

---

PS Any suggestions on how to write the ffmpeg portion of the script more efficiently/readable (without losing intended functionality) would also be welcomed.

Thanks!

---

PPS

I can successfully run the following, similar, one-pass 'crf' script without problems:

```
IFS=$'\n'

for i in `ls  *.{ts,mkv,mpeg,mpg,mov,avi,mp4,m2t,mts}`
    do

        extension=`echo "$i" | egrep -o '\.(ts|mkv|mpeg|mpg|mov|avi|mp4|mts)$'`     
        extensionFreeFileName=$(echo "$i" | awk -F `echo ${extension}` '{print $1}')        
        newFileName="$extensionFreeFileName"

        testFrameFormat='/'
        testFramsString=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  "`

        if [[ "$testFramsString" =~ "$testFrameFormat" ]]; then
            frameRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  " | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}' | head -1`
        else
            frameRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  " | awk -F "\: " '{print $2}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | head -1`
        fi

         echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n$frameRate\n\n\n\n\n\n"

                ~/bin/ffmpeg -analyzeduration 500000000 -probesize 500000000 -i "$i" -preset veryslow \
                    -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -crf 24 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 24).mkv" \
                    -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 26).mkv" \
                    -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -crf 30 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (HEVC 30).mkv" \
                    -vf yadif -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (AVC 28).mkv" \
                    -vf yadif -r "$frameRate" -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -crf 26 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "./$newFileName (AVC 26).mkv"
done;
```

---

UPDATE 11/3/2018

There were problems in my original script beyond the original problem I posted. I have since corrected the other errors and I am posting my final solution to help others who might come across this in the future when trying to build their own two-pass script.

**CAUTION: Use at your own risk. I make no warranty or guarantee that this script will work for your specific needs in your computing environment. Be sure to backup files you are encoding and execute this in a safe environment to ensure that this works correctly for you before adapting it to your production needs**

note: The following would be easier to read if copied and pasted into your preferred bash script editor (I personally like gedit which offers nice color coding if saved with an .sh extension)

```
IFS=$'\n'

#Script is designed to accept zero or one argument when executing.
#The argument is the path that contains the files you want to encode; syntax: user#bash script.sh [argument-path]
#The following commands ensure that if an argument is entered, it has a trailing '/'
#If no argument is present, it executes from the path your are currently in.

path=$1
pathLength=`echo $path | wc -c`
if [[ "$path" == "" ]]; then 
    path="./" 
    elif [[ "${path:$((pathLength - 2)):1}" == "/" ]]; then
        path="$path"
    else
        path="$path/"
fi

pathLength=`echo $path | wc -c`

#for i in `ls *.{ts,mkv,mpeg,mpg,mov,avi,mp4,m2t,mts}` #alternative to loop through multiple file extensions

for i in `ls "$path"*.mts`
    do

        #move file to local machine (useful if original file) exists on network)
        cp "$i" /tmp && echo "success"
        #format $i variable to work correctly with commands below
        i="${i:$((pathLength - 1))}"
        #assign $j variable to work with the file cp to /tmp to avoid unwanted actions on original file
        j="/tmp/$i"

        #determines file extension, base file name (without extenion), and creates newFileName variable as base file name
        extension=`echo "$i" | egrep -o '\.(ts|mkv|mpeg|mpg|mov|avi|mp4|mts)$'`     
        extensionFreeFileName=$(echo "$i" | awk -F `echo ${extension}` '{print $1}')        
        newFileName="$extensionFreeFileName"

        #get frame rate of original video in order to match frame rate when encoding (designed to work with only one video stream))
        #requires 'mediainfo' to be installed
        testFrameFormat='/'
        testFramsString=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  "`

        if [[ "$testFramsString" =~ "$testFrameFormat" ]]; then
            frameRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  " | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}' | head -1`
        else
            frameRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Frame rate  " | awk -F "\: " '{print $2}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | head -1`
        fi

        #Visual confirmation that frame rate extracted from original video makes sense (either fractional 30000/1001 or decimal 29.970 format)
        echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n$frameRate\n\n\n\n\n\n"

            #Video bit rate lookup and calculations for desire output bitrate (5 percent in this instance)
            videoBitRate=`mediainfo "$i" | grep "Bit rate  " | head -1 | tail -1 | awk -F' : ' '{print $2}' | awk -F' kb/s' '{print $1}' | awk -F' Mb/s' '{print $1}' | sed 's| ||g'`
            videoBitRate=`echo "$videoBitRate *1024 * 1024" | bc | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`

            #Note: 5 percent of original video bit rate won't work in most situations
            #My video is highly static (virtually no movement) and does not require a high bit rate for quality output
            #For encoding MPEG-2 original with moderate level of movement, I recomment a minimum of 50% for AVC and 25% for HEVC
            #For enciding AVC original with moderate movement to HEVC, I recommend a minimum of 50%
            #Ideally, you should experiment with a smaller extracted portion of video with highest motion using:
            # user# ffmpeg -ss [start time in 00:00:00.000 format] -i source -t [duration in seconds] \
            #           [video codecs like those shown below]
            #After determining what is acceptable to you, modify the target bitrates in the next two lines

            hevc05BitRate=`echo "$videoBitRate * 5 / 100" | bc | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`
            avc05BitRate=`echo "$videoBitRate * 5 / 100" | bc | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`

            # ffmpeg command and options

            ~/bin/ffmpeg -y -analyzeduration 500000000 -probesize 500000000 -i "$j" -preset slow \
                -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:v "$hevc05BitRate" -x265-params pass=1:stats=/tmp/passA -an -f matroska /dev/null \
                -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -b:v "$avc05BitRate" -x264-params pass=1:stats=/tmp/passB -an -f matroska /dev/null && \
            ~/bin/ffmpeg -y -analyzeduration 500000000 -probesize 500000000 -i "$j" -preset slow \
                -vf bwdif=0:0:0 -map 0:v -c:v libx265 -b:v "$hevc05BitRate" -x265-params pass=2:stats=/tmp/passA -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "/tmp/$newFileName (HEVC 05pct).mkv" \
                -vf yadif -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -b:v "$avc05BitRate" -x264-params pass=2:stats=/tmp/passB -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy "/tmp/$newFileName (AVC 05pct).mkv"

            # When two-pass is complete, move the newly encoded files to their target destination
            mv "/tmp/*AVC*" "/media/WinE/School Videos/"
            mv "/tmp/*HEVC*" "/media/WinE/School Videos/"
            # Remove temporary source file (NOTE: original file should still be untouched)
            rm "$j"
done;
```

Comment: For suggestions on how to improve the script, you could try https://codereview.stackexchange.com (using the output of `ls` to loop through files is bad practice, the semicolon after `done` is extraneous, prefer `$(...)` over backticks). Your indentation also seems a bit off for the one-pass script. (`testFramsString`? What is that?)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will experiment with that and incorporate it as a best practice in future scripting.

Comment: As for 'testFramsString' (other than the typo for "Frame"): It is a variable I use as part of a workaround to extract the correct FPS value from the program, mediainfo. mediainfo returns a couple different formats (depending on the source video) for the field I desire to extract and that variable in conjunction with the variable testFrameFormat and the subsequent if/then logic allows me to extract the values I need. If is a bit sloppy but it got the job done for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing spaces after `\` on line 49 and 57.

The backslash is to escape the newline that follows (not the extraneous spaces).

To overwrite file, assume yes to overwrite with `-y` (eg. `ffmpeg -y ...`).

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. (I will mark as answer when I an allowed in a few minutes)